# Aligning html grid items to wrap vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a grid of generated divs that I need to flow 0 - 9 vertically, and then wrap 10 and on to the next column. The current configuration is wrapping horizontally:

HTML

```
<div id="item-container"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 150; i++) {
  $("<li class='items grid'>item " + i + "</li>").appendTo("#item-    
  container"); 
}
```

CSS

```
li.grid {
      display: inline-block;
      border: 1px solid #333;
      background-color: #000;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #eee, #ddd);
    }
```

Current implementation in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ldh9beLn/9/

Comment: Have you tried searching for a solution to this? What have you tried?

Comment: I had tried wrapping the divs with an overflow, without luck. I know it should be a fairly simple solution, I'm just drawing a blank and my search hasn't turned up a viable option.

Comment: Tried display: table, but its only aligning in a column, not wrapping.

Comment: This might not be the right way to achieve what you want, but is this the look you are going for? http://jsfiddle.net/Ldh9beLn/10/ elements 1-9 in one column, 10-19 in the next column, etc..?

Answer (score 0):

Normal flow of the HTML elements is horizontal for inline and inline-block elements. What you try to achieve is related to columns. You need to divide your item-container element into columns.

The first option is to use CSS3 column-count or flex.

```
#item-container{
  column-count: 4;
}
```

If you need support old browsers too, you may implement js fallback. There is a jquery [plugin](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/) that might help you.

The second option is to divide your elements into columns using a container element. Wrap every 10 elements inside a column and use appropriate css for the column wrapper as below;

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 150; i++) {
    if(i%10 == 0) $("<div class='column'></div>").appendTo("#item-container");
  $("<li class='items grid'>item " + i + "</li>").appendTo("#item-container > .column:last-child");
}

.column{
  width: 35px;
  border: 1px solid;
  float: left;
  margin: 30px;
}
```

Comment: I can see what you're doing here, but when I tried to fix it to set the `column` class and `items` class in the if condition, it breaks.

Comment: can you post your code. i tried this code and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the solution, but creating two classes to toggle between `column1` and `column7`, depending on the grid layout required.

```
$('.item-container').removeClass('column7').addClass('column1');
```

and

```
$('.item-container').removeClass('column1').addClass('column7');
```

with the associated css classes:

```
.column1{
  column-count: 1;
}
.column7{
  column-count: 7;
}
```